# Show that $\sinh(x)$ is strictly monotonic.

Tags: trigonometry, monotone-functions

Is it enough to show that its derivative, $\cosh$, has no zeroes? (No $x$ satisfies $e^x=-e^{-x}$)

Comment: Almost. You also need to observe that $\cosh$ is continuous, the domain is connected, and $\cosh x>0$ for at least one $x$

Comment: Yes, adding the fact that sinh is continuous.

Comment: l think you mean monotonic, though $\sinh(x)$ may in fact also be monotonous . . .

Answer (score 2):

You should show that the derivative is strictly positive.

You could solve it as

$$
\sinh(x) = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2} \\
\frac{d \sinh(x)}{dx} = \frac{e^{x} - (-e^{-x})}{2} = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2} 
$$

Which is always greater than $0$, since $e^x > 0 \ \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Since the derivative exists all over $\mathbb{R}$, the function $sinh(x)$ is continuous as well, which tells you that it is monotone increasing.